# New to Oracle, Unsure if I'm "missing" something

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, while-loop

The following query via PL/SQL returns expected results:

```
select member_id, birth_date from ( select * from member order by member_id asc ) where birth_date > 0 and update_end_date = 29991231 and rownum <= 20;
```

It returns 20 rows of data, ordered like I want it to.

However when I incorporate a variant of that query within a while loop inside of a SQL block, it errors on the second iteration of the loop:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
    dob         number (8);
    currentDate number (8);
    mID         number (8);
    members     integer;
    i           integer;

begin
  select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') into currentDate from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Current Date: ' || currentDate);

  select count(*) into members from member where birth_date > 0 and update_end_date = 29991231;
  dbms_output.put_line('Member Records: ' || members);

  i := 1;
  while i <= 10
  loop 

    select member_id, birth_date into mID, dob from ( select * from member order by member_id asc ) where birth_date > 0 and update_end_date = 29991231 and rownum = i;

    dbms_output.put_line('Row number: ' || i || ' > Member ID: ' || mID || ' | Member DOB: ' || dob);

    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The idea is to start at the first row of the ordered results, then iterate through each row, outputting that row's results.

Eventually once I have this working, I intend to compare this data with an expected value and perform more conditional logic after that.

So unless I'm missing a fundamental "Oracle Thing" then I don't see any good reason as to why this logic fails.

I do recognize that I'm using more of a general-purpose scripting language approach to perform my logic as opposed to nested Oracle statements, but I don't see a reason why that should make a difference.

Again, could be some ignorance at play here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how `rownum` works. You can only use `rownum <` or `rownum <=`, or `rownum = 1`; you can't compare directly to anything other than 1, or use the `>` or `>=` operators.

From [Tom Kyte's article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html):

> A ROWNUM value is assigned to a row after it passes the predicate
>   phase of the query but before the query does any sorting or
>   aggregation. Also, a ROWNUM value is incremented only after it is
>   assigned, which is why the following query will never return a row:
>
> ```
> select * 
>   from t 
>  where ROWNUM > 1;
> ```

So your main query with `rownum <= 20` is fine, and in the first iteration of your loop `where rownum = 1` is also OK. But on the second iteration `rownum = 2` can never actually be true, so you get a no-data-found error.

Using your own variable for a loop iterator when you have a result set is doing more work than you need to. You could make it work by including the `rownum` in a subquery, and then filtering that in an outer query, but it won't be very pretty or efficient. You can get what you  need, I think, from:

```
declare
    currentDate number (8);
begin
  select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') into currentDate from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Current Date: ' || currentDate);

  for r in (
    select member_id as mID, birth_date as dob, rownum as rn
    from (
      select * from member order by member_id asc
    )
    where birth_date > 0
    and update_end_date = 29991231
    and rownum <= 20
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Row number: ' || r.rn
      || ' > Member ID: ' || r.mID
      || ' | Member DOB: ' || r.dob);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This only executes the query once, in the cursor, rather than partially repeating it for each value of `i`. [Read more about cursors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#i45288).

I've included the `rownum` (with an alias so you can refer to it later) which has the same value as your `i` would have. You can do anything you want with the selected values inside the loop, referring to them with the `r.` prefix (use a more meaningful name!) and the column name/alias from the cursor query.

Storing or manipulating dates as numbers (or strings) is not a good idea though, and a bad habit if you're just starting out. Always use the correct data type.

Comment: Interesting, okay so in that case I need to determine a way to iterate with a custom value for each row... perhaps dumping the output of the select into a temp_table where I can define a rowID for example?

Comment: @GabrialMacLeod - you could select into a collection and iterate over that, or use a temporary table but that's almost always overkill in Oracle (though common in SQL Server, I believe). I've added a version using a cursor loop using your original query which I think will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible there are not enough records in the result set to complete the loop. For instance, if you only have two records, asking for a record where rownum = 5 would give you a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. You could catch this in an exception block:

```
BEGIN
i := 1;
  while i <= 10
  loop 

    select member_id, birth_date into mID, dob from ( select * from member order by member_id asc ) where birth_date > 0 and update_end_date = 29991231 and rownum = i;

    dbms_output.put_line('Row number: ' || i || ' > Member ID: ' || mID || ' | Member DOB: ' || dob);

    i := i + 1;
  end loop;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
END;
```

Change the 'NULL' to handle the exception, but this should just exit out of the loop for you.

Comment: The following:   select count(*) into members from member where birth_date > 0 and update_end_date = 29991231;
  dbms_output.put_line('Member Records: ' || members); returns greater than 400,000 records, so I highly doubt it's an issue with not enough returned records as I'm limiting the iterations to 10 loops (rows)